# Setting up Ubuntu 18.10 LTS Server with Windows 10

Tags: networking, server, permissions, mount, remote-desktop

I've set up Ubuntu Server most as a storage thing as I do website and software development as well as various other things so set this up as a way to store all of my stuff as well as my families stuff so things are all in one place.

**First Problem**
I've had a couple of issues that I can't seem to figure out so I'll do my best to describe them here. My first problem is that I was trying to set up remote desktop into Ubuntu from Windows 10. I did a bit of research on it and I was going to use Windows Remote Desktop to remote into the server. The issue I'm having is my permissions seem to be wrong through the XRDP. Using the server directly is perfectly fine however when I connect from Windows 10 it seems I have less priviledges, for example I cannot mount extra drives, run terminal commands etc.

**Second Problem**
The server has 3 drives, one that runs Ubuntu and 2 that are storage drives, I have been having an issue keeping the 2 drives mounted, if it logs out or restarts etc then they wont remount themselves even though I have set them to automatically mount. Before I redid my room layout I had a separate keyboard mouse and monitor for the server, I was able to easily move files between Windows 10, Ubuntu and my iMac. For some reason since I've put everything back in, I set the storage drives with local network shares so I could map them on my Windows 10 machine and copy files that way however everytime the machine restarts or logs out, the local network shares get removed and I have to do them again, something I cannot do through XRDP, I can't seem to figure out how to keep them shared perminantly.

**Third Problem**
When I have been able to get in there are some things I'm unsure of and wanted to clarify:

As soon as I log in, I get prompted to authenticate colour profiles, this can be 4+ popups but when I type my password in all of them and then the remote desktop connection simply closes with no errors or anything. I've looked into ways to edit the files to stop the popups coming up however whenever I open the files they are read-only and I can't find a way to edit and save them. This one kind of links with the permissions error.

One more thing going on the look, some things seem different for example in XRDP when I am connected, there is no dock, have to click Activities in the top left corner, The files icon no longer uses "Files" it uses Nautilus - is this normal?

I have not used any form of Linux in quite a while so I'm still trying to get familiar with it again so I do apologise if these are easy to answer questions and can be found in documentation, I did struggle to find relative and up to date information on most of it, either seems some of the stuff I found were out of date or have not been fixed as they still seem to be having problems.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some ideas that can help you with your issues...

**Issue 1**

just an idea but I think you are encountering an expected issue when remoting to Ubuntu.  There is a technology called polkit that basically grant a user the right to perform actions on the ubuntu machine.  When locally logged in, the user has more rights than when connecting remotely....(some info can be fount at [http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073)](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073)

**Issue 2**

cannot help with this one because unclear to me if you are talking about drive redirection or physical drive on the machine.  If you are talking about drive redirection within remote session, this was an known issue with fusemount in Ubuntu 18.04.  We think it's fixed in recent version of xrdp packages but need to be confirmed

**Issue 3**  - Please read till the end..:-)

This is expected.  With no additional configuration at xRDP/Ubuntu level, you will have the default Gnome desktop displayed in your remote session and you will have some polkit policies showing up...(like color dispaly popup).  To fix that, you have to create specific polkit deviation files and configure some login script to ensure that Ubuntu gnome desktop is displayed

You can fix **manually** the look'n feel by either using instructions in this post (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13590)

In two words, you have to install gnome Tweak and enable Ubuntu Dock + select proper theme to be used in remote session

For the **popup**, you can have a look at this post on how to fix the issue (http://c-[nergy.be/blog/?p=12073](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073)  and be sure to read this post as well before proceeding ([http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043))

in two words,  create a file called /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-colord.pkla and copy the following content

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Theses issues can be easily tackled by using the xrdp-installer-v1.x.sh script that automate all these post-configuration actions (see [http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14093)

Hope this help 
Till next time